# How to loop through text file and assign values to a dictionary in Python3?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

i am trying to backup cisco switches with python script. First i do ssh then I have a separate txt file where i collected all ip addresses and want to loop one by one using dictionary. But it only chooses first ip addresses and then script stops. I am so new in Python and i am sure i  am doing something wrong. See teh code below. Please correct me where i am doing wrong.

```
#Import script dependencies
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import getpass
import logging

#Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='debug.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger("netmiko")

#Read from a list of hostnames to connect to
switches = open('hosts.txt', 'r')
switches = switches.readline()
switches = switches.splitlines()

#Get Username and password from input
userName = input('Username: ')
passWord = getpass.getpass()

#Loop to process switches in switches.txt file
for host in switches:
   Cisco_Catalyst = {
           'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
           'ip': host,
           'username': userName,
           'password': passWord,
   }

#Netmiko SSH Connection Handler
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**Cisco_Catalyst)

#open file to write command output
file = open(host + '_backup.txt', 'w')

#Execute commands
output = net_connect.send_command('skip-page-display')
output = net_connect.send_command('show run')

#Print output to console screen
print(' -------------- Output from ' + host + '--------------')
print(output)
print()
print()

#Write output to file above
file.write(output)
file.close()
```

Comment: In your for loop, you are creating a new dictionary at every iteration i.e. it gets overwritten. You would want to initialize the dictionary before the loop and then maybe use ip address as it's key and the rest as its values. Or, you could create a list and append this dictionaries. Not sure of the data structure that ConnectHandler expects but it will be a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

If by assigning values to a dictionary, you mean to append the dictionary values, then you must instantiate a dictionary Cisco_Catalyst outside the loop and append each switch data into the dictionary.
Try:

```
Cisco_Catalyst = {}
for host in switches:
   Cisco_Catalyst.update({
           'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
           'ip': host,
           'username': userName,
           'password': passWord,
   })
```

Comment: Hi there,

I tried above mentioned but it does not work. I mean it does not connect any of the switches now.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open(r'switch_ip.txt', 'r') as inp:
    for line in inp:
        line = line.strip()
        with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(hostname=line, username='admin', password='admin')
            print("Successful Connection to " + line)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).